# Win server 2008 change port of RD Gateway

Tags: remote-desktop-services

Is it possible to change the port used by RD Gateway. I know its integrated with IIS and it uses port 443 (SSL) so i've changed my IIS bindings to use a different port for SSL communications. however, I can't find any way to specify the RD gateway port in the RD client. Has anyone ever done this before?

Reason I'm asking is, my ISP just recently blocked port 80 and 443 so I am forced to use another port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not supported on Windows 2008 R2, but will be supported in Windows 8.
http://microsoftplatform.blogspot.com/2011/10/running-rd-gateway-on-different-port.html

However, to connect to an address on a different port, you would use the following syntax.  In my example, i'm connecting to port 444

http://rdg.domain.com:444/